# Can a single Wi-Fi client connect to multiple access points concurrently?

Tags: wireless-networking

It seems like all Wi-Fi routers can be many access points with a single piece of hardware. That is, with a firmware like OpenWrt, I can create many access points (not sure how many, but at least 3 is possible) for the same 2.4MHz Wi-Fi router.

If so, can a client, such as a smartphone or a laptop, theoretically also connect to multiple access points (having different NAT IP addresses) concurrently, if the software supports it? For example, connecting to a Wi-Fi home network and to an IoT device that acts as an AP for incoming commands, concurrently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible. There’s a problem though: The radio (there’s only one) can only be tuned to one channel, so all networks you want to connect to simultaneously need to be on the same channel.

For example, here’s an extract from `iw phy` output:

```
valid interface combinations:
         * #{ IBSS } <= 1, #{ managed, AP } <= 8,
           total <= 8, #channels <= 1, STA/AP BI must match
```

(IBSS means Independent Basic Service Set, AKA ad-hoc mode.)

You can use `iw` to create a new interface on the hardware:

```
iw phy <your phy> interface add <interface name like wlan0> type managed
```

You can then use it like any other interface, within the constraints described above.